# Where do X/Y coordinates measure from in Adobe CS3 and Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-cs3

I have a project where there are several PDF files.  I'm using Illustrator to make these.  It seems the point/line of origin is inconsistent from image to image (file to file).

Where is the point of origin, by default, in CS3 Illustrator?  It would be nice if, while I was positioning images, I could just say, "OK, x coordinate is 5.5 inches in this document, so it is 5.5 in that one,"  but it seems this is not the case.

Anyone know how Illustrator sets these parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Adobe livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/en_US/Illustrator/13.0/help.html?content=WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-631c.html):

> Rulers help you accurately place and measure objects in the illustration window. Rulers appear at the top and left sides of the illustration window. The point where 0 appears on each ruler is called the ruler origin. The default ruler origin is located at the lower-left corner of the artboard.

However,

> To change the ruler origin, move the pointer to the upper-left corner of the illustration window where the rulers intersect, and drag the pointer to where you want the new ruler origin.
>   As you drag, a cross hair in the window and in the rulers indicates the changing ruler origin.

But:

> To restore the default ruler origin, double-click the upper-left corner of the illustration window where the rulers intersect.